# $\lim_{E\ni(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y}$, where $E=\{(x,y):y>x^2\}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

By intuition, since the numerator has a higher degree, the value of the limit should be zero. Is there a rigid proof for this statement? Particularly, how does one solve this particular limit? I can't use polar coordinates and I have tried using the squeeze theorem but they don't seem to work(at least, I haven't found a way that does)

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What happened throgh the curve $y=-x^2$?

Comment: edited, thanks!

Comment: Do you truly mean $y>x^2$ or rather $y\neq x^2$?

Comment: yes I truly mean that--this question came directly out from the book

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $y>x^2$ you have for $0<x^2<y<1$

\begin{eqnarray*} \frac{|x^3+y^3|}{x^2+y}
& \leq & \frac{|x^3|}{x^2+y} +  \frac{|y^3|}{x^2+y} \\
& \stackrel{0<x^2<y<1}{\leq} &  \frac{|x^3|}{x^2} +  \frac{|y^3|}{y} \\
& \leq &|x|+ y^2 \stackrel{(x,y)\to (0,0)}{\longrightarrow} 0\\
\end{eqnarray*}